# Hibernate doesnt see path

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some problems with hibernate. I am sharing my code.
The error I am getting

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java"
>   -Dfile.encoding=windows-1250 -jar C:\Users\kubci\IdeaProjects\FinalProject\target\hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:56 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>       INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {[WORKING]}
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:56 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>       INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:57 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>   
>       INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure
>       WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator
>       INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loginpanel]
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator
>       INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator
>       INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections
>   
>       INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
>       maj 29, 2018 7:41:58 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect 
>       INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>       Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException:
>   Unable to load class [pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginConnection]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:150)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
>         at pl.Final.Project.Main.main(Main.java:19)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginConnection
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
>         ... 9 more

This is my Main .

```
package pl.Final.Project;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginUser;

import javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;
import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static ArrayList<LoginUser> getUsersList(){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        ArrayList<LoginUser> usersArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            List customerList = session.createQuery("FROM pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginUser WHERE id=1").list();
            for(Iterator iterator = customerList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                LoginUser c =(LoginUser) iterator.next();
                usersArrayList.add(c);
            }
            tx.commit();

        }catch (HibernateException e){
            if(tx!=null){
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return usersArrayList;
    }
}
```

and cfg.xml and hmb.xml files

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM

        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loginpanel</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <mapping class="pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginConnection" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name = "pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginUser" table = "tuser">

        <meta attribute = "class-description">
           Login Customer mapping
        </meta>

        <id name = "id" type = "int" column = "id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name = "login" column = "login" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "password" column = "password" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "name" column = "name" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "surname" column = "surname" type = "string"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I don't know what to do. I had another project with this code and it works. I did copy and paste, change some details like path etc. There are some errors and I think here is the problem:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException:
>   Unable to load class [pl.Final.Project.entities.LoginConnection]

Comment: Error is as stated -- the JVM cannot find the definition for `LoginConnection.class`. Figure out why the class is not in the jar and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you encountered says clearly that LoginConnection class can't be loaded. Yet there is no LoginConnection class to be seen. You've added LoginConnection as mapping class for Hibernate session, but source code of LoginConnection is missing. Maybe you should create LoginConnection class first, before it can be loaded?

Or did you accidently write LoginConnection instead of LoginUser?

Comment: @Jakub Madej: Have you been able to resolve this issue?